# Django dependency: hmac?

Tags: python, django

I been doing a lot of changes today including environment variables, Pyscripter and updating Python from 2.7.5 to 2.7.7. One of these changes now causes an error to be raised when I try to *runserver* on my Django site.

```
(myEnv)PS C:\Users\Josh\.virtualenvs\myEnv\tumblr> python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 72, in _configure_logging
    from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.http.request import (HttpRequest, QueryDict, UnreadablePostError,
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core import signing
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 45, in <module>
    from django.utils.crypto import constant_time_compare, salted_hmac
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

I've tried updating Django, but I have the most recent version. Next is to uninstall Django and reinstall it, if that won't mess up my project. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion I found online at the link below was to reset your virtualenv since this error can occur after upgrading to Python 2.7.7. Run

```
# virtualenv /path/to/your/virtualenv/
```

and that should reset it with the latest python.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749491

For me what worked was to downgrade down to python 2.7.6 and now my django 1.6.5 app is working again.